# Sending Message To User From Remote Computers

Tags: windows-command-prompt, open-source, instant-messaging, messenger

I have 4 networks. 10.22.227.0\24, 10.28.43.0\24, 10.0.3.0\24, 10.0.6.0\24. 
In total there is some where around 250 users. What i would like to be able to do is send the user a message from my computer or my laptop. I used msg from the CMD line and Net send from the CMD line. This is great and all but really only works well with in the local lan and at best its a 50/50 shot.

I do not (at this time) have a DC or AD set up. 
All sites are networked together through a site to site VPN and a Fiber Tunnel. 
All the Computers are Win 7 Pro & 10 Pro

Is there another way i can send messages to users even if i need to install some small (light weight) software (preferably free) would be fine.

Comment: Sounds like you need a proper [instant messaging](https://slackhq.com/) system. Also, Active Directory.

Comment: @EEAA Is this a one way chat of can they chat to other users. I only want to be the able to start a chat with them and i dont want them to be able to chat some one else. I also done really care if hey can message me back I rather yell at them and them not to be able to respond back :)

Comment: The reliability problems you're experiencing are directly tied to the fact that you do not have AD running. I can't imagine what process you went through to think that managing 250 clients without AD would go well.

Comment: @EEAA Unfortunately i took over this network and there is a few things im working on at them moment including bringing up an AD/DC. I thought it would be better to get rid of the windows XP computers and then 10/100 main switches and the Walmart style routers on the network first and replace them with commercial grade equipment.

Comment: AD should be Job #1. Having a consistent means of centralized management will assist you greatly through the rest of the phases of your improvement.